# Using the dash character in property of object

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload to AWS S3 directly using plupload. Everything works great on Firefox 22 but not Firefox 18.

In  the older version of Firefox, I get the error `NS_ERROR_CANNOT_CONVERT_DATA` and I have narrowed it down to this line:

`up.settings.multipart_params['Content-Type'] = 'image/png';`

The reason this doesn't work is because the multipart_params isn't supposed to be an array/object. However, this was the only way I could get the `-` in the property name.

Is there anyway I can use a dash without using square brackets?

Answer (score 0):

No, a '-' is not valid in a javascript variable name. Using it in the way you are using is the only 'workaround' I know of.